# How to add material to a blueprint created?

Tags: unreal-4, materials

My project has a cube and a capsule.

**Below you can see an inserted cube of the modes tab. Beside a capsule inserted from a blueprint created by me:**

[image]

**I can drag the material I created and use it in the cube, but not in the capsule:**

[image]

**Note that the cube has a tab to insert the material:**

[image]

**But the capsule I created does not have that same tab:**

[image]

I would like to know what components I would have to add to the capsule so that the capsule could have a material.

Comment: Thanks for adding the extra pictures! This will surely help other people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Materials can only be applied to some subclasses of UPrimitiveComponent, like UStaticMeshComponent. If you select the StaticMeshComponent of your Capsule actor in its components list (in the Details tab), you can drag the material into its slot on there.

**See below:**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

You might not be able to drag and drop the material into the viewport on the actor in some circumstances.